Barrier Reverse Convertible Coupon
I want to ask regarding Barrier Reverse Convertible,
I got this from https://bookdown.org/maxime_debellefroid/MyBook/barrier-reverse-convertibles.html
"The price of this barrier reverse convertible is 99.76%, which is composed of:
Long 1y Zero-Coupon Bond: 98.02% (assuming 2% interest rate for the sake of the example).
Short 1y ATM 80% DIP: 6.50% (assuming 20% implied volatility and 3.5% of dividends).
Guaranteed coupon: 8.4% paid at maturity –> PV(8.4%) = 8.23%.
Let us assume that the 24 bps left (100% - 99.76%) are earned by the bank as a commission."
My question is that, how to calculate the guaranteed coupon ? because 2% + 6.5% is 8.5% not 8.4%
Thank You
